# Translate \n new line from Char to String in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to convert `#"\n"`, a Char, to `"\n"`, a String. I used

```
Char.toString(#"\n");
```

and it gives

```
val it = "\\n" : string
```

Why does not it return `"\n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Char.toString` from the [documentation](http://sml-family.org/Basis/char.html#SIG:CHAR.toString:VAL).

> returns a printable string representation of the character, using, if
>   necessary, SML escape sequences.

It also specifies that some control characters are converted to two-character escape sequences and `\n` is one of it.

To return a string of size one, use [`String.str`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string.html#SIG:STRING.str:VAL).

```
- String.str(#"\n");
val it = "\n" : string
```